# Assigning uninitialised class instance to a class pointer causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault, instance

Recently I've come across strange C++ behavior I cannot understand. I have a header file like this:

```
1:  struct LogLevel {
2:  public:
3:    static const LogLevel ERROR;
4:
5:    LogLevel(int id) : _id(id) {}
6:
7:  private:
8:     int _id;
9:     std::string _name;
10: };
```

And then separate C++ implementation file:

```
1:  LogLevel l = LogLevel::ERROR;
2:  const LogLevel LogLevel::ERROR(1);
```

Line 1 causes segmentation fault. I know it has something to do with uninitialized memory, but I can't understand what is going on behind the bars.

If you swap lines 1 and 2 in implementation file, then everything is OK.

What is very confusing for me is, that everything is also OK if you just comment-out line 9 from header file with definition of std::string member.

Does anyone have sensible explanation ?

Comment: It's not really clear what it is you don't understand. Clearly, if line 1 runs before line 2, then terrible things will happen, right? (Or is that not clear to you?) Do you think somehow they'll run in the right order ever if you place them in the wrong order?

Comment: OK, I should have been clearer. In this particular example both implementation lines 1 and 2 are in one file. But what if they are in separate files like: loglevel.h is header. loglevel.cc includes loglevel.h and contains initialization line 2. Then there is separate file main.cc which includes loglevel.h and contains line 1. Does C++ compiler guarantee that they will be executed in order ? Is there better way to initiallise static const members ? In JAVA for example this would happen on one place atomically - you don't have to separate declaration and initialization into two separate files.

Comment: If they're in separate files, no guarantee is made about the ordering. But this is not a sensible way to do things anyway. Whatever problem you're trying to solve, there's a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the same unit, static variables get initialized in the order of their definitions.

So when you have the line:

```
LogLevel l = LogLevel::ERROR;
```

the variable `LogLevel::ERROR` has not yet had its constructor run. This causes undefined behaviour. The reason this UB manifests itself as a segfault could be because you copy a `std::string` by value which has not been initialized, so its internal pointer will be wild.

Reversing the order of the definitions fixes the problem, as then `LogLevel::ERROR` does exist when you try and assign it to `l`.

NB. It'd be preferable to make `l` `static`.  This prevents you accidentally referring to it from another unit, so you avoid the *static initialization order* problem. If you intentionally want to refer to it from another unit, you'll have to make sure that you do not access it in that unit before `main()` has been entered.

Comment: I kind of did not realize that this assignment is making copy of the instance :) If `const LogLevel *l = &LogLevel::ERROR;` is used, no problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a value until it's initialized.

```
LogLevel l = LogLevel::ERROR;
```

The default copy constructor attempts to copy `ERROR._name` to `l._name`, even though `ERROR._name` hasn't been initialized yet. This is undefined behavior and can cause a crash. As you noticed, the solution is to change the order of the two lines of code.

Comment: Those two lines kind of look like global declarations to me - wouldn't this run into a global initialization order problem?

Comment: That problem refers to globals in different units. Within the same unit, things are guaranteed to happen in their definition order.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Should have specified, I meant later in development. Something like a logger sounds like a thing that would be used across different compilation units (assuming the program is big enough to have multiple in the first place)

Comment: I put all my static definitions before any function code , to try and avoid this.  (And then I stop using non-zero static definitions in future projects as I found out the hard way how much of a pain they are).